# Exibir Form com animação (gif) enquanto um while é executado

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo necessito verificar se um processo está sendo executado no sistema, para isso uso uma função (*IsRunningProcess*).

No entanto, gostaria de exibir um form (*FormProgress*) que contém uma gif de *loading* enquanto um processo específico roda. O problema é que a animação não é mostrada, parece que o form fica congelado.

Também tentei com os componentes **Progressbar** e **Gauge** utilizando um **Timer**, mas também não obtive sucesso. Para exemplificar segue uma parte do código.

```
while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
begin
  FrmProgress.Show;
  FrmPrincipal.Hide;
end;
FrmProgress.Close;
Application.MessageBox('Operação concluída com sucesso!', 'Ferramentas',
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION + MB_OK);
FrmPrincipal.Visible := True;
```

Comment: Este form deve impedir o acesso às outras janelas? Seria como uma splash screen? se for posto um exemplo interessante aqui depois.

Answer (score 5):

Com `ProgressBar` e `Gauge` você provavelmente não teve sucesso porque precisaria estar atualizando o `FrmProgress`.

Porque com `ProgressBar` e/ou `Gauge`? Não sei como é o comportamento de um gif animado no Delphi. Já tentei colocar uma vez, não era nativo o uso de gifs animados e então substitui por outras formas, geralmente `ProgressBar` ou `Gauge` porque sempre preciso dar um feedback de tempo de percorrido no processamento.

Para atualizar o form conheço três formas:

1. FrmProgress.Update;
2. FrmProgress.Refresh;
3. Application.ProcessMessages.

As duas primeiras (*Update e Refresh*) você aplica só no formulário (*FrmProgress*) e somente ele processa as atualizações de display. Infelizmente não sei a diferença entre os dois. Mas ambos fazem uso do método Repaint, que também pode ser chamado diretamente: `FrmProgress.Repaint;`.

Na última, a `Application.ProcessMessages` você envia uma ordem ao sistema inteiro para processar toda informação que ainda não foi processada no display.

Para todas as opções uma informação mais aprofundada, por fonte, seria interessante.

Sobre o seu problema, eu não sei o que é feito nesse método `IsRunningProcess` e nem porque você usa ele em um `while`, mas na verdade ele pode ser usado para implementar um desses métodos que te mostrei e então remover a impressão de programa "travado".

Seria:

```
while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
begin
  FrmProgress.Show;
  FrmPrincipal.Hide;
  FrmProcess.Refresh;
  // ou FrmProgress.Update;
  // ou Application.ProcessMessages; // esse, em threads, costuma dar problemas
end;
FrmProgress.Close;
Application.MessageBox('Operação concluída com sucesso!', 'Ferramentas', 
  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION + MB_OK);
FrmPrincipal.Visible := True;
```

---

#### Uma sugestão para teste

Não sei o que tem nessa sua função `IsRunningProcess`, mas arriscaria dizer que `FrmProgress.Show;` e `FrmPrincipal.Hide;` não precisariam estar dentro do `while`. Acredito ser processamento desnecessário.

Tente assim:

```
FrmProgress.Show;
FrmPrincipal.Hide;
while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
begin
  FrmProgress.Refresh;
  // ou FrmProgress.Update;
  // ou Application.ProcessMessages; // esse, em threads, costuma dar problemas
end;
FrmProgress.Close;
Application.MessageBox('Operação concluída com sucesso!', 'Ferramentas', 
  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION + MB_OK);
FrmPrincipal.Visible := True;
```

Comment: O Gauge no `FrmProgress` é exibido ao usar as `procedures` (`Refresh`, `Update` ou `Repaint`), ainda fica "congelada", sendo que nenhum progresso é exibido.

Comment: Usando o `Application.ProcessMessages` o progresso é exibido.

Comment: Testei a sua sugestão e também funciona ao colocar a colocar o `FrmProgress.Show` e o `FrmPrincipal.Hide`, mas não acredito que a `procedure IsRunningProcess` esteja travando toda a aplicação, visto que com o `Application.ProcessMessages` funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira fácil de fazer seu form exibir a imagem girando seria utilizar `Sleep` e `ProcessMessages`, outra forma seria através do uso de `Threads`

```
frmProgress.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
frmProgress.Postition := poScreenCenter;
frmProgress.Show

while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
begin
  Sleep(200);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

FrmProgress.Close;

Application.MessageBox('Operação concluída com sucesso!', 'Ferramentas', 
  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION + MB_OK);

FrmPrincipal.Visible := True;
```

Para impedir que usuários interajam com  o sistema pode implementar ainda o seguinte:

```
procedure frmProgress.onDeActivate(Sender: TObject)
begin
    If frmProgress.CanFocus then
      frmProgress.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: Usando o `Application.Messages` funciona perfeitamente, mas não entendi o que você quis dizer ao aplicar o `SetFocus` ao formulário, visto que na `procedure OnDeactivate` o formulário não estará mais ativo, portanto, ocorrerá um erro ao setar o foco à janela inativa.

Comment: Faltou um ´CanFocus´, vou corrigir!

Comment: O intuito do SetFocus e fazer com que, enquanto o firm estiver ativo, se alguem clicar fora dele, retorne o foco, semelhante a um modal, @zapSys

Answer (score 0):

Delegue o processamento para uma thread em segundo plano. Voce pode fazer isso usando métodos anonimos:

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin
      frmProgress.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
      frmProgress.Postition := poScreenCenter;
      frmProgress.Show
      end);
    while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin
          label1.text := formatFloat('#00.00% concluído...',AlgumValor);
          //Sendo que AlgumValor é uma var publica atualizada pelo 

'nome_do_processo'

end;

  end).Start;
frmProgress.close;
```

no exemplo, monitoro o andamento do processo. Sempre que quiser atualizar o form chame um método Synchronize.

No exemplo abaixo eu mostro um contador que atualiza o form a cada 40 numeros

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin
      frmProgress.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
      frmProgress.Postition := poScreenCenter;
      frmProgress.Show
      end);
    //while IsRunningProcess('nome_do_processo') do
for AlgumValor:=0 to MaxNum do
    If AlgumValor mod 40 = 0 then
        TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure ()
          begin
              label1.text := formatFloat('#00.00% concluído...',AlgumValor/MaxNum);        
    end;
      end).Start;

frmProgress.close;
```